# Digits of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

For the sequence $ a_n=\frac {(1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n}{2} ,$ with $n$ an integer and $n \ge 0,$ I calculated a few terms. I noted that for the first $12$ terms, the last digits are $1,1,3,7,7,1,9,9,7,3,3,9.$ Then, I noticed that every $12$ terms have the same last digits with the same order. How can we prove that and furthermore what if $n$ is a prime?

Comment: Note that $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+a_n$.

Comment: Also note $a_{n} + a_{n+6} \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$

Comment: Why should $n$ being prime matter?